# How to find the value of convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

$$\sum_{n>=j}^{\infty }\frac{(1-\beta)^{n-j}*\lambda^n}{(n-j)!}$$

$j$ is a constant positive integer and $0<\beta<1$ also a constant.

This series converges, but I want to know the convergent value

If can, how to do that? or find the approximate value.

Thank you so much.

Comment: and what do we know about $\lambda$?

Comment: for your sum we get $${\frac {{\lambda}^{j}}{{{\rm e}^{ \left( -1+\beta \right) \lambda}}}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m = n - j$. Then $m$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$ as $n$ ranges from $j$ to $\infty$. Thus

$$\sum_{n = j}^\infty \frac{(1 - \beta)^{n-j}\lambda^n}{(n-j)!} = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(1 - \beta)^m\lambda^{m+j}}{m!} = \lambda^j \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{[(1 - \beta)\lambda]^m}{m!} = \lambda^j\exp\{(1 - \beta)\lambda\}.$$

Comment: All to easy!  ;-) +1

Comment: Oh my.....I have to review the mathematic. Thank you!!